# Preprocess (populate, generate) files with the content of other files

Tags: node.js, npm, yaml, preprocessor, populate

I'm going to explain what my problem is using a representative example.

Let's say I have these 2 configuration files:

```
# product-conf.file
seo_title: general_title
seo_description: seo_description
seo_canonical: seo_canonical

product_id: general_id
title: general_title
intro: general_intro
```

.

```
# service-conf.file
seo_title: general_title
seo_description: seo_description
seo_canonical: seo_canonical

service_id: general_id
title: general_title
products: list_products
```

As you can see, the 3 first lines (configuration fields) are exactly the same. I'm actually using YAML for these files. I would like to have pieces of code in maintainable files and include them with calls. I need a preprocessor for these. Something like:

```
# snippet-seo.file
seo_title: general_title
seo_description: seo_description
seo_canonical: seo_canonical
```

.

```
# product-conf-master.file

@include snippet-seo

product_id: general_id
title: general_title
intro: general_intro
```

.

```
# service-conf-master.file

@include snippet-seo

service_id: general_id
title: general_title
products: list_products
```

The preprocessor will read all the master files in `/masters/*`, attend all the calls and substituting them for the appropriate snippet from `/snippets/` and saving the result in `/`

I'm doing the call with `@` but I can choose whatever other format is suitable for the chosen preprocessor. I used this way because it strongly resembles to the SASS directive `@extend` or `@include`.

What is the best and easiest way I can achieve this? A package for node would be my first choice.

Comment: Have you thought about combining the files into a combined YAML file using the merge key facility to define the common parts and either use that directly (distinguish what to use on toplevel names) or write out the different YAML files from this combination?

Comment: Yes, that may help. With your input I now have been able to find more info about this ( http://yaml.org/type/merge.html )
However, still I don't know what to use to pre-process (merge) these files. The consumer of these files needs the files processed. The same way as browsers need CSS, not SASS, to put it in perspective.

Comment: For preprocessing you need to use some generic templating. But if you use the merge key, and a single source YAML, you can easily split that source with a few lines of python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need to pre-process the files you can solve this with a small YAML processing program (you might be able to do this using some node based programming).

```
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
master = pathlib.Path('master.file')
data = yaml.load(master))

common = data['common']
for file_name in data:
    if file_name == 'common':
        continue
    data_out = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
    # you can leave out the following two lines of code if you do a safe_load()
    # but you will lose the ordering in your output file
    for k, v in common.items():
        data_out[k] = v
    for k, v in data[file_name].items():
        data_out[k] = v
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as fp:
        yaml.dump(data_out, stream=fp)
```

Given the following input in file `master.file`:

```
# YAML master file
common: &COMMON
  seo_title: general_title
  seo_description: seo_description
  seo_canonical: seo_canonical

product-conf.file:
  <<: *COMMON
  product_id: general_id
  title: general_title
  intro: general_intro

service-conf.file:
  <<: *COMMON
  service_id: general_id
  title: general_title
  products: list_products
```

running the program gives you two files, `product-conf.file`::

```
seo_title: general_title
seo_description: seo_description
seo_canonical: seo_canonical
product_id: general_id
title: general_title
intro: general_intro
```

and `service-conf.file`:

```
seo_title: general_title
seo_description: seo_description
seo_canonical: seo_canonical
service_id: general_id
title: general_title
products: list_products
```

It is also possible to have the three parts in separate input files instead of values in a combined file.

---

Alternatively if your real input files are not going to include anything that is handled in a special way by `cpp` you can do:

```
cpp -P -include master.in -o service-conf.file service-conf.in
```

with `master.in`:

```
seo_title: general_title
seo_description: seo_description
seo_canonical: seo_canonical
```

and `service-conf.in`:

```
service_id: general_id
title: general_title
products: list_products
```

this gives the same `service-conf.out` as with the previous example. `product-conf.in` would of course work in the same way.

The `-P` option for `cpp` suppresses debug output comments and `-include` includes the argument as if the first line of the input file has the preprocessor directive:

```
#include "master.in"
```

you can also make that explicit and leave out the commandline option.

Comment: Thanks @anthon ! 
When I implement the solution I will answer myself here.
(Can't upvote as I don't have enought reputation... )